# Jquery strike through specific list item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am learning jquery and to practice and a as a portfolio piece I am making a simple list website. I want to be able to click on the checkbox I have beside the specific list item and have it cross out only that item. I've tried a few methods that haven't worked and I'm not sure what the best way of doing this is.

Here is my Html:

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
  <div id='bigitems'>
    <li>
      <h2 class="listHeader">Big Items</h2>
        <div class="bigappendbuttondiv">
          <button id="bigappendbutton">Append text</button>
          <label for="bigappendbutton" class="appendbutton"><p class="plus">+</p></label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput" class="striker" name=""/>
        <label for= "checkboxInput"> </label>
      </div>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="listitemtext" >
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput2" class="striker" name=""/>
        <label for= "checkboxInput2"> </label>
      </div>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="listitemtext">
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput3" class="striker" name=""/>
        <label for= "checkboxInput3"> </label>
      </div>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="listitemtext">
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput4" class="striker" name=""/>
        <label for= "checkboxInput4"> </label>
      </div>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="listitemtext">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".striker").click(function(){
    $(".striker").closest("li").addClass("checked")

  });
});
```

Using this it adds the "striker" class to every `li` when I only want it to add to the one in the same div as the checkmark button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$(this)` reference here,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".striker").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("checked");
  });
 });
```

`this` inside of the event handler will point to the element, on which the event got triggered. If you use a selector which was used to bind the event, then definitely it will select all the elements and perform the requested operation.